# knitr and knit_print with HTML output - dispatch not working

Tags: r, shiny, knitr, r-markdown, dt

I have a shiny app ([radiant.data](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/radiant.data/index.html)) that uses `knitr` to generate reports viewable inside the application (*R > Report*). Because the output is displayed inside a shiny app I need a render function for something like a DT table to be displayed (i.e., convert to `shiny.render.function`). This all works fine.

Now, however, I want to use a [custom print method](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/knitr/vignettes/knit_print.html) to handle rendering so I can just use `DT::datatable(mtcars)` with `knitr` and `knit_print.datatables` to generate a `shiny.render.function`.

Below some example R-markdown that includes the `knit_print.datatables` function i'm using. `chunk1` and `chunk2` show a `shiny.render.function` as intended but the `chunk6` shows nothing. If `screenshot.force = TRUE` I get a screenshot from `chunk6` but that is not what I want either.

Example R-markdown to be processed with `knitr::knit2html`

````
```{r chunk1}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(screenshot.force = FALSE)
DT::renderDataTable(DT::datatable(mtcars))
```

```{r chunk2}
knit_print.datatables <- function(object, ...) {
  DT::renderDataTable(object)
}
```

```{r chunk3}
knit_print <- knitr::knit_print
knit_print.datatables(DT::datatable(mtcars))
```

```{r chunk4}
getS3method("knit_print", "datatables")
```

```{r chunk5}
class(DT::datatable(mtcars))
```

```{r chunk6}
DT::datatable(mtcars)
```
````

I realize the R-markdown above, although reproducible if you have `knitr` and `DT` installed, looks a bit weird but when I export the `knit_print.datatables` function properly I get the same result in my application (see example output below).

[image]